# How do you intercept response text with request interception in puppeteer?

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I know how to get the url, I couldn't find much on the page response text however.

```
        await page.on('request', request => {
            console.log('INTERCEPTED: ' + request.url());
            request.continue();
        });
```

How would I log the page response text?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    await page.setRequestInterception(true);
    await page.on('requestfinished', async (request) => {
        var response = await request.response();
        try {
            if (request.redirectChain().length === 0) {
               var responseBody = await response.buffer();
               console.log(responseBody.toString());
            }
        }catch (err) { console.log(err); }
    });
    await page.on('request', request => {
        request.continue();
    });
```

response.text() literally will always return null, its another redundant feature of puppeteer however the above works just fine to get the page response which apparently is only present when the request fully loads. ill never get over how many features of puppeteer literally seem to do nothing lol

Answer (score 2):

You have to call `setRequestInterception` before binding to request

```
await page.setRequestInterception(true);
page.on('response', (response) => {
    console.log('RESPONSE RECEIVED');
    console.log(response.status + ' ' + response.url);
});
page.on('request', request => {
    console.log('INTERCEPTED: ' + request.url());
    request.continue();
});
```

Comment: I'm aware of that, I don't want the url I want the response text. Thanks.

Comment: That I think you should be able to get using `response.text()`.

Comment: literally .text returns nothing url and status work but nothing for text

Comment: Can you share the url?

Answer (score 1):

You can find information about `response.text()` [here](https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v5.2.1&show=api-httpresponsetext). It could be used like so:

```js
page.on('response', async (response) => {    
    console.log(await response.text());
});
```

But the problem might also be with the termination of your script. The response you're looking for might not arrive before the end of your script. Imagine you have something like this:

```js
await page.setRequestInterception(true);      
page.on('request', request => {            
    request.continue();
});
page.on('response', response => {
    if (response.url().includes('scripts'))
        console.log(response.url());       
});

await page.type('#search', 'foo');
await page.click('#send-search');
await context.close();
await browser.close();
```

then you can't be sure that a url with "scripts" will arrive before the end of your script. If it doesn't, you won't see anything in the console.

If you want to wait for a particular response, and do something with its text, it's better to type:

```js
const res = await page.waitForResponse(response => response.url().includes('scripts'));
console.log(await res.text());
```